# TypeScript Type union not working as expected

Tags: typescript

I wonder why the following does not work:

```
const GUEST = 0;
const ADMIN = 1;
type Role = typeof GUEST | typeof ADMIN;

const filterPerRole = (
    users: any[],
    role: Role,
): any[] => users.filter(user => user.role === role);

[GUEST, ADMIN].map(role => filterPerRole([], role));
```

I get the following error on the second argument of filterPerRole:

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Role'.
```

The following does not fails though:

```
const guestUsers = filterPerRole([], GUEST)
const admintUsers = filterPerRole([], ADMIN)
```

I find it a bit confusing that I have to explicitly cast again to make it work:

```
[GUEST, ADMIN].map(role => filterPerRole([], role as Role));
```

Comment: hmmm the GUEST and ADMIN are resolved into numbers inside an array declaration... what if the array's type will be declared specifically as `Role[]` I wonder... But yeah, it's very inconvenient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript infers the type of `[GUEST, ADMIN]` to `number[]` - it is a mutable array of numbers.

You can force the array to be treated as constant - `[GUEST, ADMIN] as const`. The inferred type is `readonly [0, 1]`

Thus, you can change your code to the following:

```ts
const roles = [GUEST, ADMIN] as const;
roles.map(role => filterPerRole([], role));
```

An alternative is to give explicit type to the array:

```ts
const roles: Role[] = [GUEST, ADMIN];
roles.map(role => filterPerRole([], role));
```

On top of that: the title is not correct. `A | B` is an UNION of A and B, not intersection.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA4gVQKIGUAqMC8MAMBuAKFElgEEARAWQEkA5LGARkKgE8AHAUxgCUQAbbtjZcQAM3jJ0MAD4wRncTAo1ahIuGgwxAS35ROAJwAKRvoIYAKAjFswArhCMQAXDACGYVgG0AugBobO0MBTjdzTkCASjdPH18sAD4HJ0MIADpdfSNLRyMklKN0kItMMpgSzij1Yi1KiAZvRFQ0f2UqOgT3BtqoQnr0gFt3dktKgqyDEzNQyz82yqjqmAICIA)